# Compiler warns about string conversion - is it because of the double quotation marks?

Tags: c++

if I enter 5, I want it to show "May"
but what they show is always warning, how can I make it work?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int month;
    char *m_name[] = {"   ", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May",
                      "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
    cout << "Enter month: ";
    cin >> month;
    if (month >= 1 && month <= 12)
        cout << m_name[month];
    else cout << "Illegal month";
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler warnings:

```
main.cpp:8:70: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]
                       "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"};
                                                                      ^
main.cpp:8:70: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]
main.cpp:8:70: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]
main.cpp:8:70: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]
main.cpp:8:70: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]
main.cpp:8:70: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]
main.cpp:8:70: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]
main.cpp:8:70: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]
main.cpp:8:70: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]
main.cpp:8:70: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]
main.cpp:8:70: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]
main.cpp:8:70: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]
main.cpp:8:70: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*' [-Wpedantic]
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code, instead copy the code and paste it into the question. With the [right formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), your code will have syntax highlighting, and it will also be possible for us to copy the code so we can test it ourselves. Also please give us the *exact* output you get from your program, and the output you expect it to have.

Comment: Just to answer the title (and nothing else): no, double quotes are correct for more than one character. Single quotes are intended for single characters.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure that this is what you have compiled?

Comment: What was the warning? It works for me without any warning.

Answer (score 7):

The warning is probably because of the `char*`. Change it to `char const*`.

Explanation: String literals have the type `char const[N]`, where `N` is the number of characters in the string + 1 for the NUL at the end. Normally an array of this type would only be convertible to `char const*`, but a special rule used to exist that allowed string literals to be converted to `char*` for C compatibility. This is an unsafe conversion so compilers warn against it.